# tmux causing bold fonts in vim

Tags: terminal, vim, osx, tmux

I have installed `tmux` with `vim`, using the solarized colorscheme and airline plugin. All is good until I start `tmux`, where all the font turns bold and the airline status bar is looking weird. I have heard this is a common problem when using iTerm2 which I am.
I have tried literally every solution I can find and nothing seems to work

Here is what `echo $TERM` is displaying:

- Using tmux - `screen`
- Not using tmux - `xterm-256color`

I have added `set -g default-terminal "tmux"` to my `tmux.conf`
and I have added `[ -n "$TMUX" ] && export TERM=screen-256color` to my bashrc file.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the color theme asks for more color than exist in the `tmux` terminal description, and vim is using bold to replace some of the missing colors.

Rather than

```
set -g default-terminal "tmux"
```

use a terminal description which has a comparable number of colors, e.g.,

```
set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"
```

If your terminal database has "tmux", it likely has the other, since both were added in [May 2015](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#t20150502):

```
# 2015-05-02
#       + remove unnecessary ';' from E3 capabilities -TD
#       + add tmux entry, derived from screen (patch by Nicholas Marriott).
#       + split-out recent change to nsterm-bce as nsterm-build326, and add
#         nsterm-build342 to reflect changes with successive releases of OSX
#         (discussion with Leonardo B Schenkel)
#       + add xon, ich1, il1 to ibm3161 (patch by Stephen Powell,
#         Debian #783806)
#
# 2015-05-17
#       + remove screen-bce.mlterm, since mlterm does not do "bce" -TD
#       + add several screen.XXX entries to support the respective variations
#         for 256 colors -TD
```