# Why does showconsolefont have different output in tmux?

Tags: arch-linux, tmux, tty, fonts

I'm running an arch linux system with no window manager or desktop environment (right now). I use tmux when I need multiple terminals. When I run `sudo showconsolefont` on my tty (no tmux), I see the expected set of symbols, but when I open tmux and run `sudo showconsolefont`, I see a different set of symbols that repeats itself.

My font is `ter-124b`, from the Terminus family.

[image]

In the screenshot, the top output was captured from within tmux and looks identical to how it was displayed when I ran `sudo showconsolefont`. The bottom output contains different symbols, but if I redirect it to a file and then `cat` the file, they look the same. `diff`ing them also reports that they are identical.

**Why is the output of showconsolefont different in tmux?** I thought the point of that command was to display all available symbols in the current font. Since I'm using the same font inside and outside of tmux, I don't understand why there's any difference. I'm sure there's some simple linux font concept that I'm missing here. Could someone point it out to me?

I tried checking the value of `$TERM` if I'm in tmux and ensuring that it defaults to `linux` (the same as `$TERM` in my tty), but that hasn't made any difference. (`set -g default-terminal "linux"`)

Comment: May possibly help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/237530/135943

Comment: The problem is apparent if you're familiar with the technical area.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Could you please explain? I'm sure I'm just missing a simple concept here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

short: `tmux` can't display all 256 items in a font

long:

Refer to the source code, which is a little awkward since (see *[KBD – Linux keyboard tools](http://kbd-project.org/)* webpage) prefers tarballs, but you can use the git-cloning advice to be able to [browse the source](http://git.altlinux.org/people/legion/packages/kbd.git).  The [`showconsolefont`](http://git.altlinux.org/people/legion/packages/kbd.git?p=kbd.git;a=blob;f=src/showconsolefont.c;h=da2bb96f9a98fe36d4eceb36f5d3b03fd902dccc;hb=HEAD) program does this

- [opens](http://git.altlinux.org/people/legion/packages/kbd.git?p=kbd.git;a=blob;f=src/getfd.c;h=58522cb077cf546329324ea1f85e91ca14acdfb3;hb=HEAD#l57) the specified device,
- [verifies](http://git.altlinux.org/people/legion/packages/kbd.git?p=kbd.git;a=blob;f=src/getfd.c;h=58522cb077cf546329324ea1f85e91ca14acdfb3;hb=HEAD#l29) that it is a *console*,
- [gets](http://git.altlinux.org/people/legion/packages/kbd.git?p=kbd.git;a=blob;f=src/showconsolefont.c;h=da2bb96f9a98fe36d4eceb36f5d3b03fd902dccc;hb=HEAD#l146) the current mode, to see if it is using UTF-8,
- [makes](http://git.altlinux.org/people/legion/packages/kbd.git?p=kbd.git;a=blob;f=src/showconsolefont.c;h=da2bb96f9a98fe36d4eceb36f5d3b03fd902dccc;hb=HEAD#l171) a dummy (trivial) screen-map
- [gets](http://git.altlinux.org/people/legion/packages/kbd.git?p=kbd.git;a=blob;f=src/showconsolefont.c;h=da2bb96f9a98fe36d4eceb36f5d3b03fd902dccc;hb=HEAD#l172) the current screen-map
- [prints](http://git.altlinux.org/people/legion/packages/kbd.git?p=kbd.git;a=blob;f=src/showconsolefont.c;h=da2bb96f9a98fe36d4eceb36f5d3b03fd902dccc;hb=HEAD#l182) the array...
- [for each row](http://git.altlinux.org/people/legion/packages/kbd.git?p=kbd.git;a=blob;f=src/showconsolefont.c;h=da2bb96f9a98fe36d4eceb36f5d3b03fd902dccc;hb=HEAD#l188), it remaps the characters in the array to show the font
- [restores](http://git.altlinux.org/people/legion/packages/kbd.git?p=kbd.git;a=blob;f=src/showconsolefont.c;h=da2bb96f9a98fe36d4eceb36f5d3b03fd902dccc;hb=HEAD#l203) the mode and screen-map for the console

The reason why `showconsolefont` can show 256 items (rather than say 256 - 32 control characters) is because it remaps the codes sent directly to the console.  Actually that would be *33* controls because `0x9b` is handled differently.  Close enough.  `showconsolefont` is writing characters that appear to be printable, but is row-by-row changing the characters which are actually drawn.

One thing that you may notice is that all of the changes to the console device use the file descriptor for the actual device, while the array of characters is written to the standard output.  When you run this *outside* tmux, those are the *same device*.  But running *inside* `tmux`, the standard output is to a *different* device (a pseudo-terminal, which separates the special mapping from the characters.  If you redirect the shell to the console, e.g.,

```
$ tmux
$ sudo su -
# exec >/dev/console
# showconsolefont
```

you will be able to see *part* of the interesting characters.  But the pseudo-terminal will not show carriage-return/line-feeds as expected, and the status line for `tmux` may not be drawn properly:

[image: redirecting showconsolefont inside tmux]

versus (outside `tmux`):

[image: ordinary showconsolefont]

There might be a way to set root's terminal modes to get readable output, but this is not what `showconsolefont` or `tmux` will do without some work.